# Define a list variable in xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

In my xsl transform the filename is passed as a parameter to the stylesheet. I want to do a certain set of actions if it is in a certain filelist. Right now I'm doing it this way;

```
<xsl:param name="specialFiles" select="'|a.xml|b.xml|'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($specialFiles,concat('|',$FILENAME,'|'))" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="abc" />
        </xsl:when>
        .....
        .....
```

This works, but quickly becomes messy when the *specialFiles* list grows. Is there a way to declare it like an array, and lookup quickly?

**EDIT**: This is the code I'm using to transform, I just print everything to stdout

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("1.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

    File xmlFile = new File(args[0]);
    String baseName = xmlFile.getName();   

    transformer.setParameter("FILENAME", baseName); // pass the basename of the file
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile ), new StreamResult(System.out));
```

**EDIT 2:**
I just managed to do this in a slightly different way, I embed an xml fragment inside the stylesheet and use an xpath expression on it in

```
<specialFiles>
    <name>abcdef.xml</name>
    <name>sadfk32.xml</name>
</specialFiles>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:choose>       
        <xsl:when test="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/specialFiles/name/text()[contains(.,$fileName)]">
           ....
           ....
```

Comment: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/12/xslt-variable-arrays.html

Comment: What version of XSLT, which processor are you using and how are you calling it? The obvious "array-like" construct in XSLT would be a fragment of XML with a sequence of elements, one for each value, but whether and how you can pass nodes as parameters to the stylesheet is processor-specific.

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm using version 2.0 using a very simple java code. I pass a single value to the stylesheet and then check if the value is in a list.

Comment: 2.0 is the version of XSLT, which processor are you using? Saxon?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your "simple java code"? Do you use `javax.xml.transform` or s9api or something else?

Comment: @IanRoberts sure, I have updated the question. It's a very simple code, nothing fancy. This runs on a linux system where a shell script will call this program passing different xml files

Comment: Re your latest edit, a test of `document('')/xsl:stylesheet/specialFiles/name = $filename` would be simpler as well as more accurate (from your original question it looks like you want cases where the `filename` is _exactly_ one of the specialFiles, not simply a substring of one of them).

Comment: The approach you've used is in fact compatible with XSLT 1.0 as well as 2.0.  Are you _sure_ you're using an XSLT 2.0-capable processor (i.e. Saxon 9)?  If you don't have Saxon on your application's classpath then the XSLT processor behind `javax.xml.transform` will only support version 1.0.  The complicating factor is that it is _not_ an error to pass a `version="2.0"` stylesheet to a processor that only supports 1.0 - it drops the processor into "forwards-compatible" mode where it will silently ignore instructions it does not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a xml fragment embedded within the stylesheet:

```
<specialFiles>
    <name>abcdef.xml</name>
    <name>sadfk32.xml</name>
</specialFiles>
```

So a simple xpath on it can be used to verify certain name is in the list or not,

`<xsl:when test="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/specialFiles/name= $filename">`